# Security benefits to force users to change their password at first login

Tags: password, security

When I consider `chage` command, I found that I can force users to change their password at first login with following command:

```
$ sudo chage -d 0 <user-account>
```

Has this work any security benefits for the system?

Answer (score 0):

Assume you give the user their first password using some insecure media, like email or papernote. If someone (let's say Eve) happens to see that note, she could login with the same password.

Making password a `one-time-password` removes the possibility of a second login. And if the wrong person makes the first login, well you are likely to found out soon enough anyway.